# Can you directly modify the indirect blocks of an inode in user space?

Tags: c, storage, inode

Is there a way in user space to directly modify the indirect block pointers in an inode?

I was reading this paper http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Documentation/Minix3/Inode.pdf but what I gathered from it, like it's title says, it's manipulating inodes, not explicitly modify blocks within the inode.

I realize this sounds like a terrible thing to do, I do not have any intention of doing something like this for production use, this is just for my own knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some filesystems(ext*fs, not sure about minix) optimize and write data(<60 bytes) into the block pointer array of the inode.

In that case you can just modify last 12 bytes which are corresponding to indirect block pointers.

You cannot access the block pointer array in user space; however, you can do the hack of just create a file of 60bytes and then try to read its content.

Comment: That's rather interesting.  Could you elaborate on how to access the block pointer array of the inode?

Comment: you mean in user space?

Comment: Yes, in user space.

Comment: No you can't access the block addresses written over there. The only thing you can hack is just create a file of  60bytes and then try to read its content.

Comment: Mind adding that to the actual answer?

Comment: No, that trick won't work. All sane operating systems will zero the contents of uninitialized files.

Comment: @duskwuff can you elaborate?

Comment: If you "just create a file of 60 bytes", the file will be empty. Just because it may be stored in the inode doesn't mean you get to see the other contents of the inode in the file.

Comment: Hmm care making that an answer?